# How to fit my data in the [-1:1] range while keeping their relative differences?

Tags: python, numpy

For a machine learning course, I read data with multiple columns:

```
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/housing/housing.data'
cols = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT', 'TGT']
boston = pd.read_csv(url, sep=' ', skipinitialspace=True, header=None, names=cols, index_col=False)
```

This data is then centered, so their average is (very close) to 0:

```
boston_centered = boston - boston.mean()
```

I'd now like to fit this data in a range from -1 to 1 while keeping their relative distance to each other. I.e. `.max()` will return a value `<= 1` and `.min()` will return a value `>= -1`

Example: If my data is `-2, -1, 1, 2` it should become `-1, -0.5, 0.5, 1`.

I could loop over every single data point and and calculate their relative distance to the min/max value individually, but this would probably be not very performant. Is there a simpler way to do that?

Comment: Try dividing by the max value?

Comment: Actually, a question. If you have `-1, -1, 0, 2`, do you want `-0.5, -0.5, 0, 1`? Or `-1, -1, -.33, 1`?

Comment: @Iluvatar First comment: Wouldn't this cause problems when the absolute min value is bigger than the absolute max value? Second comment: I'd like to get `-0.5, -0.5, 0, 1` - their relative distance should be kept the same. Basically I'm looking for a way to "**resize**" the data

Comment: Yes, so you'd use something like `max(-smallest, largest)` to divide by. Edit: basically the answer given by @Ioa_in_, though you don't need the `abs` around the `max` as it's always positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain the mean you have to divide each value by `max(abs(min(data)),abs(max(data)))`

Comment: Shorter: `max(abs(data))`

Answer (score 1):

`boston_centered = (boston - boston.mean())/abs(boston - boston.mean()).max()`

Or in two steps

```
boston_centered = boston - boston.mean()
boston_cnorm=boston_centered/abs(boston_centered).max()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the MinMax normalization of scikitlearn.preprocessing : 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html